# Move from socket to webservice: double timeout

Tags: web-services, rest

I have a client/server application that communicates via tcp/ip sockets over an often unreliable wireless network.
To make it responsive in case of a connection error,I created this protocol.
1) client sends a request
2) server confirms reception of request (1 second timeout)
3) server processes while client wait(may take up to 10 seconds) (20 seconds timeout)
4) server sends response
Sometimes the request command get lost (the client sends it over an open connection but the server never receives it), but with this protocol I know immediately if the command has been received and is going to be processed.

What I'm asking (I've made some test with RESTSharp and ServiceStack) is: is possible to do something like this with a webservice? where a client before the response receives a confirmation that the request has been received?

Thanks,
Mattia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange to see this type of error handling in Application code since if a HTTP request wasn't successful it will already throw an Exception.

To get a confirmation receipt in Application code you would need to add a 2nd request implementing some kind of [Push Event / Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) technique to get the server to notify the client of different events, e.g. what Request Ids have been received.

Comment: Yes, it will throw and exception, but after how long?
If request goes well, I can wait 20 seconds for the data response, but if goes bad, I need to know immediately (or in one second...).

I'd love to move to a REST architecture, but for me is fundamental to know almost immediately if the client is waiting 10s for the data to be processed or is waiting 10s for a "unreachable host" or something like that...

Comment: You can set a specific Timeout property in your HTTP or ServiceStack clients. You can minimize 'perceived response times' by using async calls and not blocking the UI and letting them continue to use the UI while the HTTP request is being processed in the background.

Comment: Well, not really, the user needs to use immediately the data that is querying, so I can async the request (I'm already doing it with my socket stack) but it won't solve the problem.
My issue is: 
1) if everything is ok I can wait up to 20s (more means that the data processing is having problem,another issue)

2) connection is not ok, server has not received my request, or is unreachable, I need to know in 1s

Comment: The user must be certain that is waiting for data, this is a priority, so I just need to know if I can control it with webservices. 
If someone tells me that is definetely not possible, being webservices based on a httprequest/httpresponse protocol that do not allow or control an acknowledge of something similar in the middle, I'll stay with my socket tcp/ip protocol...

Thanks!

Comment: "if everything is ok" can mean different things to different people. Not hearing a response for N secs could mean firewall rule dropping packets, or server taking a long time to respond. I'd never build this logic in the App layer, I've never seen or heard this done over HTTP (even for web clients). Use and configure the HTTP clients unless you've discovered a reason not too.

Comment: It doesn't seem so strange to me to have a protocol where a client sends a request and receives immediately (<1s) a server response "I got your request and I'm starting to process it", and then the client waits up to 20seconds for the actual data response.
But if not receives the first ack (for ANY reason,from unreliable wifi to crashed server), it immediately tells the operator that it has no connection.
What I'm trying to understand if this behavior can be replicated with a webservice.

Comment: oh great, I just noticed that you make servicestack so I guess you're reliable :)
I'm kidding, I'm just really trying to understand if what I do with my tcp/ip protocol is replicable with webservices

Comment: HTTP is a single HTTP Request + HTTP Response application protocol. Most HTTP middleware stacks will buffer the response so it can automatically calculate the required `Content-Length` Response header (as required by HTTP). You can get around this in ASP.NET hosts by setting `context.Response.BufferOutput=false` which will instead send a [Chunked encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) Response, where your server can call `Response.Flush()` to flush the current buffer to the client.

Comment: Ok, so I can sort of make an HTTPRequest and get immediately a "partial" HTTPResponse, then after processing I get the rest. This may be what I'm looking for... can you even point me to a client and server samples of this? Or something similar that I can realize with servicestack?
Thanks

Comment: This is generally outside most web service frameworks. You'll need to access ASP.NET's  low-level `HttpResponse` types to modify the behavior + work with the low level `HttpWebRequest` C# clients and consume using their Async APIs to start receiving data as soon as its ready.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll try also to explore the WCF with TCP binding and see if they offer better control of the connection.